# Lumen logs not reported to Bugsnag

Tags: laravel, lumen, bugsnag

I have a Lumen 8 app where I want to use `bugsnag` to be notified when my app is logging some error.

I have followed the [docs](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/lumen/) by:

- Adding `bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel` module
- Adding the service provider in my `app.php`
- Adding the `BUGSNAG_API_KEY` in my `.env` file
- Adding the bugsnag channel in my `config/services.php` file

  ```php
  'channels' => [
      'stack' => [
          'driver' => 'stack',
          'channels' => ['single', 'bugsnag'],
      ],
      'bugsnag' => [
          'driver' => 'bugsnag',
      ],
  ],
  ```
- Adding this in the `Exceptions/Handler.php` file

  ```php
  if (app()->bound('bugsnag') && $this->shouldReport($exception)) {
      Bugsnag::notifyException($exception);
  }
  ```

If I have an exception that is triggered by my app, it is reported correctly to my bugsnag dashboard (and I am notified by email), but if I have a log like `Log::critical("something crashed");` the log is correctly written in my log file but nothing is sent to bugsnag.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to send the errors to Bugsnag by creating my own `LogServiceprovider` and add this:

```
public function boot() { 
   Log::listen(function(MessageLogged $message){ 
     Bugsnag::notifyError($message->level, $message->message); 
   }); 
}
```

But since nothing like this is mentioned in the documentation I'm wondering if this is the right way to handle this.